# Gemfile.lock not used by Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: bundler, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gemfile

In Heroku:

> Gemfile.lock ensures that your deployed versions of gems on Heroku
>   match the version installed locally on your development machine

Is it the same with Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic beanstalk uses bundler so if you have a Gemfile.lock it will be respected. You could also package dependencies along with your app using `bundle package`.